# Getting "Too many authentication failures" from every ssh server I've been using

Tags: networking, ssh, authentication

About two weeks ago one of the servers at my workplace started giving me this error and then another one. Now even my local server (on my home network) gives me this error too. What does this mean? I used `ssh-keygen -R` but it didn't help. The command

```
ssh  -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive
```

helped with the servers at work but at home I get the following error:

> Too many authentication failures
>
> Permission denied (publickey,password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This link may help answer your question in regards to the error message of "Too many authentication failures"

[superuser.com: Too many authentication failures for *username*](https://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username)

- Per the manpage for `ssh-keygen`, the `ssh-keygen -R` command:

  > Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file

  So keys are removed are those from ssh-servers that are configured on 
  your **client's** `~/.ssh/know_hosts` files and have no
  effect on the error you are receiving from the server side.
- With regards to your home server and the message:

  > Permission denied (publickey,password)

  The server may be configured to only allow key-based authentication. You may need to check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes` if you are trying to authenticate with a username and password.
- Finally you may want to execute the `ssh` command with the `-v` option (adding up to 3 v's for more detailed information) in order to view helpful messages about how your ssh client is interacting with the ssh server. You may also require the `-i' option in order to use the proper key configured in your servers`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

  Your command may look like this:

  `ssh -i '~/.ssh/workplace_server_rsa' -v user@workplace_server_address`

Comment: Thanks, the last tip worked. Just, is there a way to set the keyfile for each host permanently without having to specify it in each ssh comand?

Comment: I found the answer to my comment here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/

Answer (score 1):

> Too many authentication failures

This message is caused by having too many failed authentication attempts given the permitted limits enforced on the remote SSH server. This could mean that you've multiple identities added in your SSH agent and your SSH client offered too many which didn't work.

Here are few suggestions:

- Add `-v` to see if that's the case (you've using too many identities).
- List added identities by `ssh-add -l`.
- Remove failing identity from the agent by: `ssh-add -d`.
- You may also deletes all identities by `ssh-add -D` and re-add only relevant one.
- If you've access to SSH server, check the `MaxAuthTries` option (see: [`man sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)).

  <sup>Related post: [What is a connection for `sshd_config`'s 'MaxAuthTries' limit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418582/21471)</sup>
- If none of this help, make sure whether you're using the right credentials or file.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the answer has been already given, let me share how I manage to fix it.

1.`ssh-add -D` remove all the RSA entries.

2.`vi ~/.ssh/known_hosts` remove all the rows manually. Press `dd` for each row.

3.`ssh-keygen -q -f ~/.ssh/xyz_rsa -t rsa` create *xyz_rsa* and *xyz_rsa.pub* files

4.`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/xyz_rsa user@server_address` copy your private key from your local(client) machine to remote(server)

5.`ssh-add ~/.ssh/xyz_rsa` add new RSA entry

6.`ssh-add -l compare to ssh-keygen -l -f xyz_rsa.pub`

7.**Reboot** your system as the changes may not be applied on the fly.